# Print pdf with valid icon without using a pdf viewer - C#

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I need to print a pdf file have digital signature by code (C#) without using a pdf viewer (Adobe Acrobat or Foxit Reader).

But the problem I have is that when printing out, the print displayed in the signature area is "Signature Not Verified".
When opening Acrobat or Foxit, signatures with valid icon can be printed.

I understand what the decision of a valid icon is depends on the pdf reader. But is there any solution that prints pdf file without opening any pdf reader?

I have attached 2 pictures (2 copies). 1 is printed by code, 2 is printed by a pdf reader.

[Image "Print by Acrobat or Foxit"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmn6a.jpg)

[Image "Print by code (C#)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbDyS.jpg)

[Update: Image: print with Spire.PDF library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wHGm.jpg)

Comment: Essentially your print result is correct, the appearance of those signatures in the pdf is the one with the question mark. Acrobat and Foxit change it. If you also want to print a changed appearance, you have to check your pdfs for signatures of this kind before printing and manipulate the pdf for printing. Thus, you need to use a pdf library here. Which pdf library would you use?

Comment: I don't use any libraries. I just included the path of the pdf file to be printed to the printer's process list. Can you recommend me any library that can help with this? thanks!

Comment: I have tested 1 library to print pdf files.
It is Spire.PDF.
But at this time the print just prints out "tick icon", and words like: Reason, Location and date time are not displayed. I have updated the printout image on my question.

Comment: I don't really know Spire.PDF, but I also would not have expected a library to do what you want out-of-the-box (because it's strictly speaking the wrong thing to do). I'd have thought about using a library and manually identifying that kind of signature and manipulating it. I would have used itext (because I know it) but any general purpose pdf library should do.

Comment: can iText library print pdf?. As i know iText can be only used for reading or building PDF's. Can you guide me?

Comment: You can use itext to preprocess your pdf (manually identifying that kind of signature and manipulating it) and in a second step use your original printing code to print the manipulated pdf. The details are difficult to outline while I'm merely on a smart phone...